# Masonry.js issue on wordpress live site, but not local dev site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am working on this site: http://lisarevson.com/

It's using a wordpress theme with Masonry.js.

I downloaded the site and cloned the DB and the site looks fine locally on MAMP Pro.

Yet on the live site, as you can see, the masonry tiles slide up from the bottom and overlap each other.  I'm a bit at a loss why it happens live but not locally, and therefore how to fix.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. Everyone was on the right track I found the answer:  [imagesLoaded](http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#imagesloaded).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // initialize Masonry
    var $container = $('#content-blog').masonry();
    // layout Masonry again after all images have loaded
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
      $container.masonry();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you put your js function on header :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#wrapper").vids();
});
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#content-blog').masonry({columnWidth:323});
});
</script>
```

I think you should move it to footer after mansory.js has been called.

Answer (score 1):

Steve try also

```
var $container = $('#content-blog');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
columnWidth: 323,
itemSelector: '.post'
});
```

and as Le says move your script from the top to the bottom and place it after masonry.min.js

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

try to call masonry on window.load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#wrapper").vids();
});
jQuery(window).load(function($){
$('#content-blog').masonry({columnWidth:323});
});
</script>
```

Actually what happens is masonary is executed first then images loads on live server (due to net speed) while on local both load simultaneously